# Game on a square grid (part II)

Tags: soft-question, game-theory, recreational-mathematics

Related to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359416/game-on-a-square-grid), where there the solution was unexpected for us.

Let $n,m$ be positive integers, $n \le m \le n^2/2$.

The board is $n \times n$ square grid.

Phase 1:

- Two players, $A,B$ make $m$ moves, where at each move each of them
  color uncolored vertex of the grid red.

Phase 2:

- $A,B$ take moves in turns.
- A move is picking two red vertices and drawing a straight line between them.
- If the line intersects another line or passes through a third red vertex,
  the game ends and the player who made the move loses the game.
  Two or more lines are allowed to end at the same vertex.

Is there winning strategy depending on $n,m$?

If the general solution is hard fix $m$, say let $m=\lfloor \frac{n^2}{4} \rfloor$

Comment: why would there ever be no valid moves?

Comment: @Squala You are right, draw is impossible, I edited.

Comment: It says a move is coloring a vertex (or more than one vertex?) red, and then it says a move is drawing a line (segment, presumably) between two red vertices. Which is it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks, you are right. I edited, trying to clarify about two types of moves.

Comment: In phase 1, do the players move simultaneously or alternately?

Comment: @Eilon Alternately, taking turns. Player A starts.

Comment: So a winning strategy exists by Zermelo's theorem. I guess you are interested in identifying the winner for various n and m.

Comment: @Eilon Thanks, I am not familiar with this theorem. Yes, I am interested in the winner as n,m vary. If necessary fix m.